# PrestaShop 1.7.6 images not showing when friendly-URL is switched on

Tags: image, prestashop, friendly-url

I have the same problem.
I've tried to do all classical methods like regenerate images, clear cache, regenerate htaccess.. but nothing works...

PS version 1.7.6.1
Linux Server Information # 1 SMP Wed Aug 14 08:29:59 EDT 2019 x86_64
Server software version: Apache

The NGINX server is not present on the hosting service and there are no errors on the web service and PHP side.

The server vendor indicates:
Problem only happens with SSL
no error on the webserver side
no error on the PHP side using the native PHP7.1 version

[image: Image Issue]

Any idea to solve this issue??? 
Thanks